# Which partition manager to use for dual-boot Windows, Linux on SSD?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ssd, multi-boot, grub2

I have Windows 8.1 and Linux Mint dual boot (Grub) on an SSD disk.

I want to resize Windows partition to take less space and give it to Linux. I don't want to mess up my computer, so I wanted to ask for advice first:

- Which partition editor supports all of the above?
- Which backup program can I use to do a full backup of my SSD first? I tried Macrium Reflect, but it doesn't work with Grub, my computer wasn't bootable after restore, so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Most setup media for modern Linux distros come equipped with everything to resize the original partition to make space for Linux. They'll also install a boot manager like GRUB2 and that's what your question should be about also, I guess.

Comment: I'm not sure about Win 8.1, but Win 7 came with a Microsoft utility to shrink the Windows partition.  See if that is still bundled.  Requests for software recommendations are off-topic on Super User, but there is no shortage of information readily available online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm personally a fan of [P.I.N.G](http://ping.windowsdream.com/cgi-bin/download.pl) and/or Clonezilla. They aren't super fancy looking and Clonezilla can be intimidating but whenever I use them they simply work. I've used dozens of cloning software that claim 1:1 ratio but don't always get the booting correctly. This goes without saying but make sure you create a backup before trying the suggestions below.

As for decreasing partitions I stand by [Gparted](https://www.howtoforge.com/partitioning_with_gparted) all the time. I find that sometimes changing a Windows partition through linux doesn't always work. If this is the case and Windows errors on startup, a simple automatic startup repair usually fixes the issue. The start sector and ending sector of the Win partition just needs to be adjusted appropriately.

With that being said can also try decrease it in Windows using [Diskmgmt.msc](https://tweakhound.com/2013/01/02/how-to-resize-your-windows-8-partition/). Then use Gparted to increase the Linux partition.

ANOTHER suggestion is to get fancy backing up individual partitions, in/decreasing their size, then writing them back to the drive. Then use Grub2 to detect paritions and dual boot.